# Accessing variable from one javascript file from another in using Nodejs and Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I have the following code in A.js-

```
var variableOne = k;
localStorage.setItem("vOneLocalStorage",variableOne);
```

and the following in B.js-

```
myFunction=(event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    var vOneLS = localStorage.getItem("vOneLocalStorage");
    var variableTwo = vOneLS;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World"+variableTwo;
    }
```

and also have this in render() in B.js-

```
<button onClick={this.myFunction}>Check</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

The variable k is an array of strings which I extracted and filtered using AWS-Textract. A.js and B.js are in different directories. The web page displays a Check button which on clicking gives me-

```
Hello Worldnull
```

Why is the value null? I want it to print the values of the array. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you verified component A set the value *before* component B tries to read it?

Comment: check your variable k, it should be null or undefined and then check your local storage.

Comment: Make sure you serialize the data before writing it to the localStorage:
`localStorage.setItem("vOneLocalStorage",JSON.stringify(variableOne));`